# Атрибуты кнопок

Tags: bootstrap

Когда кнопка не активна и мы её не трогаем, она "пользуется" стилями свое класса, например - btn1. Когда мы наводим на неё курсор используется атрибут :hover.
А какие атрибуты используются при нажатии на кнопку в bs3 и при последующей потере фокуса но не активности кнопки.
Для большей наглядности :
 
1 картинка - нажатая кнопка
 [image]
2 картинка - кнопка после нажатия, но курсор еще в фокусе кнопки
[image]
3 картинка - потеря фокуса кнопкой 
[image]
Какие атрибуты срабатывает в каждом из случаев, если это не атрибуты, как это контролировать?(сделать фон transparent, убрать синюю границу итд)

Answer (score 1):

```
.btn{
 font-color: black;
}

//2 картинка - кнопка после нажатия, но курсор еще в фокусе кнопки
.btn:hover{
 background: black;
}

//1 картинка - нажатая кнопка
.btn:active{
  font-color: green;
}
```

только измените цвет как хотите...

Comment: пробовал так делать, не помогает.

Comment: порядок стили тоже должна быть именно такими. Вы проверили это?

Comment: да, проверил, :hover работает, а :active - нет

Comment: тогда в место active попробуйте focus